# how to implement a tree structure in javascript in which a node contains 2 arrays inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

So, the thing is I'm not really good at Javascript (I only know some C programming) & i want to implement a tree structure in which the node contains 2 arrays inside an array.

I could help you by giving structures in C:

```
struct IndexArray {
   void *DataArray;
   void *ChildsArray;
}

struct Node {
   struct IndexArray *ContainerArray;
}
```

In short words the node contains an array & each element of this array contains 2 sub arrays.

I searched for tree implementations in javascript & i found many examples but i couldn't find an implementation similar to this one.

Comment: Are you trying to create a function which accepts parameters and returns `Array(Array(),Array())`?

Comment: JavaScript is a weekly-typed language so you don't have to define a 'type' like you do in C. Almost everything in Javascript is an object. What would like this object to do or what are the behaviours of it?

Comment: I want to create the node for this tree ? How should it be declared in Javascript ? @guest271314

Comment: @afr0ck `var node = Array(Array(), Array())` or `var node = [[],[]]`

Comment: That object should contain 2 arrays inside one big array.
something like this:
`var node = new node();`
`node.IndexArray[i]` gives access to element `i` of `node.IndexArray`
`node.IndexArray[i].dataArray[j]` gives access to element `j` of dataArray of element i of indexArray.
& similarly `node.indexArray[i].childArray[j]` 
@guest271314
@xtu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `Array` in `javascript` using `Array()` constructor or array literal `[]`

```js
function _Node(a, b) {
  this.IndexArray = [[a], [b]];
}

var node = new _Node(1, 2);
var i = 1;
console.log(node.IndexArray[i]);
```

Alternatively

```js
class _Node {
  constructor (a = 1, b = 2) {
    this.IndexArray = [[a], [b]];
  }
}

var node = new _Node(1);
var i = 1;
console.log(node.IndexArray[i]);
```

Comment: How to access elements of the sub arrays [1] & [2] ? Let's say we want to access 4th element of sub array [1] ?

Comment: Note, arrays are 0-indexed. `node.IndexArray[1][3]` would get second array of `node.IndexArray` and fourth element of subarray.

Comment: That was very useful, can i use node.IndexArray.length ?

Comment: Yes, `node.IndexArray` is an instance of `Array`, which has `.length` property. Note the `_` before `Node`, as `Node` is a `DOM` function.

Comment: OK. This should have solved the problem, thanks for helping.